# Accuracy of distance between two latitudes and longitudes points

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

Is the error of evaluating the distance between two lat,lon points bounded?

For example:
Given point a and point b (acquired by smartphone GPS) such as |a.lat-b.lat| < 10^-4 and |a.lon-b.lon| < 10^-4 what will the error of evaluating the distance without taking into account the Earth's curvature be?

Comment: I can't shake the homework-feeling on this. What research have you done? Do you consider distances in degree useful?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @Erik this is not homework, it is a coding issue that rose. Basically I want to know, if I can use euclidean distance for two points that are at most 100 meters away, or the error that will be introduced due to earth curvature will effect my measurements significantly

Comment: What do you consider "significantly"? And again the question: Do you consider distances in degree useful?